# Give a precise statement of the Second Derivate Test for functions of two variables

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

So I'm guessing this has something to do with:

$f_{xx}(x,y)$ and $f_{yy}(x,y)$ and $D = f_{xx}(x,y)f_{yy}(x,y)-[f_{xy}(x,y)]^2$

But I don't understand what the question wants. The entire question is just simply what's in the title and that's it.

Comment: What is it about the question you do not understand? It seems pretty clear to me for what the question is asking. Are you perhaps unsure of what the second derivative test is?

Comment: As @peek-a-boo said, we normally need to see where you are in the proof and some of you work thus far. How about start by stating what the second derivative test is, and what definitions you think might help us along the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question clearly just wants you to state the second partial derivative test in full, and precisely. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test):

> Suppose that $f(x, y)$ is a differentiable real function of two variables whose second partial derivatives exist and are continuous. The Hessian matrix $H$ of $f$ is the 2 × 2 matrix of partial derivatives of $f$:
> $$H(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}f_{xx}(x,y)&f_{xy}(x,y)\\f_{yx}(x,y)&f_{yy}(x,y)\end{pmatrix}.$$
> Define $D(x,y)=\det(H(x,y))$. Then if $(a,b)$ is a critical point of $f$ (i.e., $f_x(a,b)=f_y(a,b)=0$),
>
> 1. If $D(a, b) > 0$ and $f_{xx}(a, b) > 0$ then $(a, b)$ is a local minimum of $f$.
> 2. If $D(a, b) > 0$ and $f_{xx}(a, b) < 0$ then $(a, b)$ is a local maximum of $f$.
> 3. If $D(a, b) < 0$ then $(a, b)$ is a [saddle point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle_point) of $f$.
> 4. If $D(a, b) = 0$ then the second derivative test is inconclusive, and the point $(a, b)$ could be any of a minimum, maximum or saddle point.